# pyenvでPythonを PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv installのオプション付きインストールでエラーになる

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

macOS 10.13 High SierraにpyenvでPython3.6.5を PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv  installのオプション付きでインストールしようとしたところ、BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.13.6 using python-build 20180424)と以下のようなlogが出て失敗します。良い解決方法はありますでしょうか。

Xcode、command Line Tool等はインストールしています。

````
sed 's/%VERSION%/'"`DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/var/folders/8m/81qnxqq56nv378bskry80mx00000gn/T/python-build.20200603130659.66316/Python-3.6.5 ./python.exe -c 'import platform; print(platform.python_version())'`"'/g' < Mac/Resources/framework/Info.plist > /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Info.plist
ln -fsn 3.6 /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/Python.framework/Versions/Current
ln -fsn Versions/Current/Python /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/Python.framework/Python
ln -fsn Versions/Current/Headers /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/Python.framework/Headers
ln -fsn Versions/Current/Resources /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/Python.framework/Resources
/usr/bin/install -c -m 555 Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
cd Mac && make pythonw
clang -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib  -DPYTHONFRAMEWORK='"Python"' -o pythonw \
        ./Tools/pythonw.c -I.. -I./../Include \
        ../Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
./Tools/pythonw.c:214:9: warning: comparison of function 'posix_spawn' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
    if (posix_spawn != NULL) {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
./Tools/pythonw.c:214:9: note: prefix with the address-of operator to silence this warning
    if (posix_spawn != NULL) {
        ^
        &
1 warning generated.
if test "Python.framework" = "no-framework" ; then \
        /usr/bin/install -c python.exe /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m; \
    else \
        /usr/bin/install -c -s Mac/pythonw /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m; \
    fi
install: /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6m: Too many levels of symbolic links
make: *** [altbininstall] Error 71```
````

Answer (score 1):

すいません、Python等uninstallし環境を再構築したところインストールできました。